# Why does Bangladesh government need India's help to stay in power?

Tags: india, bangladesh

Can anyone explain the following news to me?

- [Bangladesh Foreign Minister Abdul Momen urges India to do whatever is needed to keep Sheikh Hasina in power](https://thehindustangazette.com/world-news/bangladesh-foreign-minister-abdul-momen-urges-india-to-do-whatever-needed-to-keep-sheikh-hasina-in-power-10934)

During his speech at a Hindu religious festival, Bangladesh's foreign minister Abul Momen said -

> “I went to India and told them (Indian government) to do whatever is needed to keep Hasina in power,
>
> "I told the Indian side that Sheikh Hasina must be sustained. Bangladesh will continue to march towards development and will truly become a country free of communalism under her leadership,” he added."

This speech brought a shitstorm in social media and local news media.

The Bangladesh government has already rigged the past two general elections and successfully demolished the opposition to oblivion. Therefore, they should be in complete control of everything.

Why does Bangladesh's government need India to stay in power?

**EDIT:** India played an active role in instating the current government of Bangladesh, which is narrated in detail [in a book written by the late president of India](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8129149052).

Also:

- [India fuelled Hasina’s decision to oust Yunus](https://www.thestatesman.com/opinion/india-fuelled-hasinas-decision-oust-yunus-1502743143.html)

Comment: It's not clear that they do. To me the whole speech reads more like the FM is threatening India with a wave of refugees if there's political instability in Bangladesh. Which of course may be rubbish talk, but who knows... I'm assuming he's using "communalism" in this [negative sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communalism_(South_Asia)) when he says B must be kept free of it.

Comment: @Fizz, *reads more like the FM is threatening India with a wave of refugees if there's political instability in Bangladesh.* --- I haven't read anything like that. Besides, close to a million Indians illegally work in Bangladesh. Bangladesh is India's one of the largest remittance sources.

Comment: FTWT, the Bangladeshi opposition called for a general strike last time Modi visited https://abcnews.go.com/International/wireStory/indias-modi-ends-bangladesh-visit-sparked-violence-76723348

Comment: @Fizz, *the Bangladeshi opposition called for a general strike last time Modi visited* --- I don't get the connection. Besides, that was not the opposition; that was a collection of non-political Islamic groups. The main opposition is either rotting in prison or executed by a kangaroo court.

Comment: So the news story is "Member of government asks regional superpower for support for his own government"...  that seems ... unsurprising.

Comment: That does not mean they "need" India's help rather they are asking India for help.

Comment: Countries are always trying to influence developments in their region. Some of the means are considered legitimate by the international community, some are not. Depending on politics in the region, the endorsement by another state may *help* or *hinder* the prospects of a government, that is not the same as *install* or *remove*.

Comment: @o.m., *that is not the same as install or remove.* --- So, you mean the late Indian president Paranb Mukherjee wrote a fictional thriller in his autobiography? So, you mean the USA never removed Mosaddegh?  So, you mean Russia never changed the regime in Mali?

Comment: @user366312, what I mean is that foreign actions might tip the scale in a precarious situation, but against a stable government it takes a foreign army to do a *regime change* -- as in Iraq, or in Panama.

Comment: @o.m., So, did or didn't India install BD's government in 2008?

Comment: @user366312, the way you put it, no. It may have *influenced the result*, which is a much lesser claim. Just because some side worked towards a result which later happened does not mean that side *caused* the result single-handedly, which a term like *installed* would imply.

Comment: @user366312, I presume you are aware of the anti-Trump stance of many European governments. Yet it was Americans who elected Biden, not Europeans who "installed" him. Yes, I'm considering India's biases and preferences **less significant** than you do, and the BD political system less prone to remote control.